# A simple birth year calculator using Kotlin

Tags: android, function, android-studio, kotlin

I start doing a simple android app for practice to calculate the age with Kotlin programming language, the error came from the line `34`, can someone help me with this and fix it to know where is my wrong because I am just very beginner

```
    package com.calcult.age.agecalcult

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var my_age_number =  ageText.text!!
        var my_month_number =  ageText2.text!!
        var my_day_number =  ageText3.text!!
        var calcult_age_button = doIT

     calcult_age_button.setOnClickListener {

         if(my_age_number.isEmpty()){

             Toast.makeText(this,"ادخل سنه ميلادك !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         }else if (my_age_number.length < 4 || my_age_number.length > 4){

             Toast.makeText(this,"ادخل سنه ميلاديه صالحه الأستعمال !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         }else if (my_age_number.length == 4){

             fun getAge(){

                val get_the_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

                 val calculat_the_age = my_age_number - get_the_year


             }
         }

     }

        }
}
```

Comment: try removing `;` from line where you are getting current year from calendar.

Comment: @KaranMer `;` it doesn't give error though

Comment: post the error log, without that it is not possible to tell what problem you are facing.

Comment: Also define what is at line number 34

Comment: Why are you defining function in if clause? it won't run.

Comment: why you aren't defining your var as Int ?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Please quote the error message you get verbatim. And as @VivekMishra said, also tell us which line in your code is line 34. Thx.

Comment: val calculat_the_age = my_age_number - get_the_year

Answer (score 0):

`my_age_number` is a String value, so you should try

```
var calculat_the_age: Int? = null
try {
    calculat_the_age = my_age_number.toInt() - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
} catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
    // my_age_number not a number

}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

return value in Int type only.

Comment: I just update my answer, try this and let me know if any issue